# No module named 'torch' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, anaconda

I am fairly new to using jupyter notebook, and I've read every forum available for this issue, with no luck.

I am running Windows 11, and I installed Anaconda, then created and activated a virtual environment called pytorchenv. My .yml file includes the following

name: pytorchenv
channels:

- defaults
- pytorch
  dependencies:
- numpy=1.16.2
- pandas=0.24.2
- matplotlib=3.0.3
- pillow=5.4.1
- pip=19.0
- plotly=3.7.0
- scikit-learn=0.20.3
- seaborn=0.9.0
- python=3.7.3
- jupyter=1.0.0
- pytorch=1.1.0
- torchvision=0.2.2

If I list all of the included packages in the command prompt, using

```
conda list -n pytorch
```

it shows that pytorch is installed as...

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pytorch                   1.1.0           py3.7_cuda100_cudnn7_1    pytorch
```

What's more, if I enable the virtual environment in the Command Prompt, It seems that I am able to import pytorch successfully

```
C:\\Users\\Nathaniel\>conda activate pytorchenv

(pytorchenv) C:\\Users\\Nathaniel\>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) \[MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)\] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import torch
>>>
```

However, when I try to import pytorch into jupyter notebook, I get the message

```
import torch
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In \[1\], in \<cell line: 1\>()
1 import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

I have been able to import pandas and numpy in jupyter notebook without issue, but I have not figured out a way to import pytorch successfully.

In case this is helpful, jupyter notebook shows that it is running on

Python 3 (ipykernel)

and running the following in jupyter notebook

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

results in

```
C:\\Users\\Nathaniel\\anaconda3\\python.exe
```

I've tried checking if there were multiple versions of jupyter notebook on my computer (there aren't).

I also checked that pytorch is installed in the same place as my other anaconda packages (it is).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you activate the environment when you ran the command of jupyter lab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notebook is running with your base environment, as indicated by sys.executable.

Two methods:

- Start Jupyter from your environment
- Register your environment to be usable by all jupyter notebooks
  For that you can find the necessary steps [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html)

Basic step is this

```
source activate pytorchenv   # or activate the environment via conda
python -m ipykernel install --user --name pytorchenv --display-name "Python (pytorchenv)"
```

Afterwards be sure to restart Juypter, then you should be able to select your pytorchenv kernel.

Comment: You are right! Starting Jupyter within my environment resulted in Pytorch importing successfully. If I understood the linked article correctly, am I right to assume that instead of using **source activate other-env** as my first line, I should reference my environment by saying **source activate pytorchenv** followed by **python -m ipykernel install --user --name pytorchenv --display-name "Python (pytorchenv)"** ?

Comment: You are right, eddited the fist line to match your case. The `--name` argument can be anything, it does not need to match your environment name, it is used internally to differenciate between the kernels but that way it is easier to remember them if you want to uninstall / change it.